# Some swipe gesture with adb input

Tags: android, shell, input, adb

Try to emulate gesture like some curve with "adb shell input". Do all command in "su" stream. How can i make curve? Find this way, but it's dont work:

```
CommandClick.su("input swipe 520 430 520 815 1000 && input swipe 520 815 675 815 1000");
```

CommandClick.su

```
public static void su(String... commands) {
new CommandClick(SU).command(commands).finish();}
```

CommandClick

```
 try {
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(command + "\n");
                dataOutputStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I want 2 swipes like one line...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `sendevent` command.

Syntax: `sendevent <device> <command> <argument> <value>`

`sendevent` sends whatever events you want directly to the input device event queue. To replicate a complex swipe, you would need to generate:

1. Start touch (aka finger down)
2. New point (aka finger move) - as many as required
3. End touch (aka finger up)

Each of the above operations consists of:

```
sendevent <device> <parameters for the operation type>
sendevent <device> 3 0 <x-coord>
sendevent <device> 3 1 <y-coord>
sendevent <device> 0 0 0    # (event separator)
```

The specific device as well as the parameters for the operation type may vary according to what device type and brand you are simulating the events on. The best way to get those details is to run `getevent`, then pipe the output of a few swipes to a file and review the output.

These links go into more detail:

1. [Tutorial on events](http://www.softteco.com/blog/android-writing-events-low-level-touch-screen-automated-shell-test-part-1/)
2. [Shell script for pattern unlock using sendevent](https://github.com/mattwilson1024/android-pattern-unlock/blob/master/unlock.sh)